# GeOrchestra impossible to access to geonetwork administration

Tags: postgresql, geonetwork, georchestra

I've installed GeOrchestra using the proposed ansible script on a Debian 8 distribution. I have kept the original settings and geOrchestra started immediately. I can login with 'geoserver_privileged_user' in the geoserver setup, but impossible to connect to the geonetwork administration when using the address HOME_URL/geonetwork/srv/.

The page ask for a login and password but 'admin' 'secret' does not allow any connection.

In the postgresql database 'admin' is present in the geonetwork users table.

Any idea on what can I try to unlock the situation?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, geOrchestra comes with `testadmin` & `testuser` users.
The passwords are identical to the logins.

More information here: https://github.com/georchestra/georchestra/tree/16.12/ldap#georchestraldif

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was the info I was looking for.